# How to integrate polyspace in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to use polyspace bug finder and code prover for my current project but, I'm not able to integrate polyspace with my IDE(eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do that:

1. install the Polyspace plugin for Eclipse
   https://www.mathworks.com/help/codeprover/gs/install-polyspace-plugin-for-eclipse.html
   With the plugin, you can launch Code Prover or Bug Finder and see the results directly inside Eclipse (no need to open the Polyspace UI to review the results)
2. since R2021b a new tool called PolyspaceAsYouCode (available with Polyspace Access) to run fast Bug Finder analysis in different IDEs (Eclipse, Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code)